# size_t or long for the size of a string containing a file?

Tags: c, file-io, malloc, unix

Suppose I want to read an entire file in memory. I'd open it in binary mode, use `fseek` to get to the end of the file, then do `ftell` to get its size.
Then I would allocate a string with the same size as the file, and just read it in, right?

The problem is that `ftell` returns a `long int`, and `malloc` should receive a `size_t` argument. Now, `size_t` *can*  be larger than `long int` as far as I can tell (I've just checked *C: a reference manual* by Harbison and Steele, and Chapter 11 mentions that `size_t` can be defined as `unsigned long long`, depending on the compiler). I suppose the opposite could be true (and that would be a real problem, since I'd be casting a `long long` into a `long`, or something like that)

So my question is how do I deal with that?

Thanks!

**edit:** thanks guys, that was really quick! I'll use `mmap` (and `posix_madvise` too, which I've found after diggin up info about `mmap`)!

Comment: The right way to deal with it is to skip all of the above, and use `mmap` or `CreateFileMapping`/`MapViewOfFile` (depending on your OS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use mmap() instead.

Comment: `mmap` here is incorrect because the string will not be null-terminated. Well, it will except in the corner case where the file size is exactly a multiple of the operating system's page size, and in that specific case, your program will crash or read into random other memory following the mapping.

Comment: The assumption of using a null-terminated string to deal with bytes from a disk file is most likely wrong, especially when the word "binary" appears. Unless the file happens to be a serialized null-terminated string, it will in general not be possible to grab those bytes and treat them as a null-terminated string, whether through mmap or any other way of reading the file. In fact, if you do, it will most likely appear much shorter than your actual file size since there will probably be a null byte at some point in the file before the last byte of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue of casting is moot. Since the smaller of the two, `long`, has a maximum of +2^31 (if signed), if you read all of that at once you'd be occupying 2GB of memory. This is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

If your files are large enough for this to be an issue, they are also large enough for the memory allocation to almost certainly fail.

Either don't worry about it, or switch to an OS specific memory mapping technique.